# zoom Issue in highchart of treemap type

Tags: highcharts

I was trying to implement a treemap, but due to huge difference in values and huge amount of data, there are lots of small bins at the bottom of Right hand side of Highchart.

So, I was trying to implement zoom in treechart to solve this issue.

But unfortunately, the zoom doesn't happen but reset zoom button is visible when zoom action is performed with mouse.

if anyone has faced this issue, please help me out.

If zoom isn't possible, is there any way I can at least select the bins using the drag selection action?

```
A general example of the zoom problem:
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5ecv9jp9/1/

Comment: How about using `drilldown` logic to allow users to zoom-in into the specific subset? Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/551ys5a6/ Bug is reported here: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4106

Comment: Thanks for the reply Pawel, but that solution adds an additional label on top of existing bins. Any way I can remove this additional label and show content label directly?

Comment: You can set additional options in `levels`, see: http://jsfiddle.net/551ys5a6/1/